# Are UserDefaults wiped when deleting an app on iOS 13/14?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

When I use plain `UserDefaults` without any other frameworks and *not* with `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`, will the UserDefaults be kept in iCloud after deletion of the app from the phone and restored from iCloud upon reinstallation of that app?

I have read in the docs that generally UserDefaults are included in the (iCloud) backup. So if a user installs the app, the app then stores some UserDefaults, the user makes an iCloud backup and then restores the phone from that backup, the UserDefaults should be there again.

But what if the user purposefully deletes my app from their phone and then reinstalls it from the store, will the UserDefaults still be there (restored from iCloud) or are they wiped out with the app deletion and not coming back with the reinstallation?

Would the user have to additionally delete the iCloud data of my app from the iCloud settings app to get rid of the UserDefaults or does it come with deleting the app (not moving to App Library)?

I basically want to start from zero after a user removes the app from the phone.

Is this different between iOS 13 and iOS 14?

Comment: I would test it for myself if I were you instead of listening to somebody that you have never met in person.

Comment: @ElTomato I think it's perfectly fine to seek advice from the stackoverflow tribe  But to each their own 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When an app is deleted from the device all local data associated with the app will be deleted too. This includes `NSUserDefaults`. However any data stored at an online service won't. For example, iCloud. The app will just fetch the data again if requested to do so by the user / developer.

I had a problem before where `UserDefaults` are getting deleted when the user delete my application. So just for educational purposes, if you don't want your data to be lost, and you don't want to store your data online, consider using `Keychain`.

For more information you can find it here: [Keychain](https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift)

Comment: In this case, I do want the data to be lost.

Comment: I verified this in my app: Deleting the app (actual deleting, not App Library) on iOS 14 does clean the UserDefaults, while the Keychain data is still there after deleting and reinstalling the app.

Comment: Keychain data is now (iOS 15+) also deleted.

Comment: @DarkDust Interesting! Do you have any source for this statement?